# How to convert a Julian date into timestamp in Snowflake

Tags: datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-conversion, snowflake-task

I have dates like 54940,55001,54970 etc.
I need to convert these dates into yyyy-MM-dd format in snowflake

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score -1):

The following steps should help:

1. Convert the julian to a gregorian date with a function (the conversion depends on your understanding of a julian date - there are different ones. If you try to google that, you may find several conversion rules)
2. Convert the string/integer to a date by using TO_DATE() https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html